# what's the max size glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE support?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I mean what's the max width and height the function support, thanks!
I tried two times height of the screen, report an error 0x8cdd which means not support.

Comment: Hard to say, it depends on multiple things, graphics card, driver, opengl version, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, always read the extension specification... in this case: [`GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/APPLE/APPLE_framebuffer_multisample.txt).

If you read the extension specification, it points you to `GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE` and an additional implementation-defined limit specific to the extension itself: `GL_MAX_SAMPLES_APPLE`.

In short, width and height cannot exceed the value of `GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE` and the number of samples cannot exceed `GL_MAX_SAMPLES_APPLE`. So you should query these values at run-time and act accordingly.

```
GLuint max_rb_size, max_samples_apple;
glGetIntegerv (GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE, &max_rb_size);
glGetIntegerv (GL_MAX_SAMPLES_APPLE,     &max_samples_apple);
```

This ought to answer your question, since this is implementation specific this is the best I can do for you. I could tell you that GLES2 requires MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE to be at least 1x1 (no joke), and Apple's extension only requires 1 sample to be supported. Neither one of these required minimum values is particularly useful so you will have to query it at run-time to find out what a real system supports :)

#### [OpenGL ES 2.0.25 Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) - 6.2. State Tables - pp. 154

[image]
[image]

Comment: Andon, thank you so much for detailed answer! I just ran the two functions in you answers on ipad 4 with ios 7, GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE is 4096, GL_MAX_SAMPLES_APPLE is 4, but strangely either width or height can't be greater than 2048, otherwise will report 0x8cdd error.

Comment: @liang: Okay, so to be perfectly clear, it is not `glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE (...)` that is generating this error code, but `glCheckFrameBufferStatus (...)`? **0x8cdd** corresponds to `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`. In order to troubleshoot this, I need to know more information, particularly the image formats and dimensions of all of your FBO attachments. Better yet, if you could edit your question to include all relevant code used to setup your FBO, that would help tremendously..